# Unable to print PDF exported from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, printing, pdf

We are facing a problem in printing the PDF maps exported from ArcGIS Pro.

We have 4 maps/PDFs (Different locations bookmarked) But they are in the same ArcGIS Project file. We are exporting the map at 300 DPI resolution.

One of the maps got printed fine, but if we try to print another one, the PDF is stuck at 90% flattening.

We are printing them on the plotter at a size of 44 inches x 58 Inches (width x height)..The PDF is also of the same size

I tried to reach the Esri support, but they said print problems from PDF is outside their scope.

Comment: So they all exported fine and it's the resulting PDFs that are giving you trouble?

Comment: I'd try Jeremy Wright's suggestion first.  You could alternately export to a tif and print it from GIMP or open it in Adobe and then print from there.  A real long shot, but you could see if one of your vector layers has a geometry issue.

Comment: Yes the PDFs export fine without errors...The PDF opens (Though the file size is big)...But not able to print...It gets stuck at "Flattening" while printing..

Answer (score 0):

you can try the "print as image" option in Adobe Reader/Acrobat's print dialog - that's Adobe's last-ditch printing troubleshooting option.

Answer (score 0):

We have been having problems both exporting to PDFs and printing exported PDFs from ArcGIS Pro 2.7.4 on a fire for the past two days. When we go to export PDFs, they'll just get stuck in "Export in Progress" and hang there. Sometimes the PDF will appear after cancelling, sometimes it won't. The same layout will export to JPG or other formats just fine, but that doesn't help when you need a georeferenced PDF for Avenza. This is happening to multiple users working off of Microsoft Onedrive.

The ones that do export won't print for us until we run them through Preflight in Adobe. Save them as a PDF/E, and run all the options in "PDF fixups" and they print just fine. Might be another way to get  them cleaned up to print, but that has been are solution.

Comment: How to convert to PDF/E? Also how to run them through preflight?